# Google Maps v1 (Deprecated) lost my release.keystore

Tags: android, google-maps, deprecated, keytool, google-play-services

I have developed android app using Google Maps v1 which is now deprecated, before v1 got deprecated I had generated maps key using my **release.keystore** but some how I **lost my release.keystore** file but I do have **MD5 hash and map key**.
So what can I do to regenerate release.keystore ?

**NOTE:** I cannot upgrade to maps v2 as this app is for some third party vendor device which **does not support** Google Play Service(which is required for maps v2).

Comment: not possible check the note in the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/

Answer (score 0):

> So what can I do to regenerate release.keystore ?

You cannot do that. Instead, you go to your backups of your development machine and restore your keystore from the backup.

Comment: @HarmeetSingh: Since you cannot retrieve it any other way, perhaps you should try your backups again.